# Backup mailbox of mail.app with applescript

Tags: macos, mail.app, backup, applescript

I would like to automate, with applescript, the back up a mailbox of mail, which is manually done with the menu "Export mailbox ...", but:
I can not set the folder where the mailbox will be saved;
I can not set the mailbox to export, it works only with the mailbox that I've previously selected manually with the following command: Click menu item...

The lines of the script, which does not work, are:

```
tell application "Finder"
  --set mboxSavePath to "HD Macintosh:Users:simonepiersigilli:Desktop:e-mail:" -incorrect command to set the save path-
  --set mboxSavePath to "/Users/simonepiersigilli/Desktop/e-mail/" -incorrect command to set the save path-
  --set path POSIX to mboxSavePath -incorrect command to set the save path-
end tell
tell application "Mail" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Mail"
  --click menu item "cesare@appuntidigitali.eu" of menu "Entrata" of menu "Caselle" of menu bar 2 -wrong command to set the mailbox to export-
  click menu item "Esporta casella di posta…" of menu "Casella" of menu bar 1 -correct command to open the menu "Export mailbox ..."-
  -- Now click the Go (choose) button
  click button "Scegli" of sheet of front window -correct command to click the button choose-
  tell application "Mail" to close the front window
  end tell
end tell
```

**UPDATE****

The intention is for the script to be run every week and it will have to backup the following inbox and sent mailboxes highlighted in red.

[image: Mailboxes]

Comment: If those are real email addresses you may want to obscure them

Answer (score 1):

GUI scripting is not that great. And can easily fail due to timing or GUI changes.

But try this:

```
set mboxSavePath to "/Users/simonepiersigilli/Desktop/e-mail/"

tell application "Mail" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Mail"


        click menu item 20 of menu 6 of menu bar 1
        delay 2
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 2
        keystroke mboxSavePath
        click button 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1

        click button 1 of sheet of front window


    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Where do I set the output (inbox and sent message) mailbox, 'cos I have more than one? What do you mean with "menu item 20...menu 6...menu bar 1"? How can I get the same result without using GUI scripting?

Comment: Did you run the script? It runs logically on the selected mailbox?  If you want to iterate over mailboxes and change destination then you will need to use lists and repeat loops. But that's not in the scope of your question. As you stated and exampled  "a mailbox" The numbers are the menu's index number in their view. Using them instead of names means the code can in most cases be used across languages.